# jQuery: FormData() doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I made a really really simple example to test whether `jQuery`'s `FormData` work or not.

**html**

```
<form id="frm" action="/fileupload" method="post">
<input type="file" name="uploadfile" />
<input type="file" name="uploadfile" />
<input type="button" id="uploadbutton" value="클릭" />
</form>
```

And I import `jQuery` cdn:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

I select some image file from my computer.

And execute folloing code in `Chrome development tool` :

```
>> var form = $('#frm');
>> form

<form id="frm" action="/fileupload" method="post">
<input type="file" name="uploadfile" />
<input type="file" name="uploadfile" />
<input type="button" id="uploadbutton" value="클릭" />
</form>


>> var formData = new FormData(form);
>> formData
```

And it shows just,

```
FormData {}
```

It doesn't contain any values. It was empty . Why does it not work?

Comment: [`formData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) is plain JavaScript, not jQuery. So as Mr. Safarov has suggested, placing a `[0]` at the end of the jQuery object will dereference it into a plain JavaScript object which will be recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon, you should try passing the element itself, but not the jQuery object:

```
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
```

Comment: `form` is also jQuery object in here(`var form = $('#frm');`). How can I select form element without using `jquery`? I did `var form = $('form')` and `new FormData(form)`  and result is same

Comment: You've selected your form object correctly. Now, you just need to get the DOM-element itself from your jQuery object, and all what you have to do is this: `form[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need call FormData.append method to add the files to FormData object.

This is my sample code of submitting a FormData object with ajax to the server.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
           <input type="file" id="file-select" multiple webkitdirectory/>

           <button id="btn-upload" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload</button>
        </div>

        <script>
          var fileSelect = document.getElementById('file-select');


          $(document).ready(function () {

             //Listen the upload button onclick
             $('#btn-upload').on("click",function(){

            event.preventDefault();

            //Check if contains files to upload

            if(fileSelect.files.length != 0){

                //Declare a FormData Object to pass the files
                var formData = new FormData();
                var fileCount = fileSelect.files.length;

                //Add the files from file-select into FormData                  
                for (var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
                {
                    var file = fileSelect.files[i];
                    formData.append("FileUpload", file);
                }

                //Make the ajax post request with FormData to your destination(eg:webservice or php page)

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://yourhost:port/something.php', 
                    data: formData,
                    contentType:false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        //Do the next process u want
                    },
                    error: function(err){
                        //Process the error
                    }

                });
            }

         });
      });
      </script>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Hope this useful with your FormData usage.