# Error by using formData

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to do this for working with a part of values from a html-form.

```
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#FORM_ADD_LANG_FILE')[0].files[0]);
    formData.append('add_lang_code', $('#FORM_ADD_LANG_CODE').val());
    formData.append('job', jobid);
var post_setting = new Array(false,false);
```

But in my console it is showing the following error and I don't know why it is

```
"TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData."
```

I generate the ajax-call by this function

```
    function getAJAXcall(processData, contentType, formData, callback) {
        var returnValue = {
           url: '".$global['serverurl']."module/".$m['ID']."/code/cms_data.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: formData,
           success: callback
        };

    if (processData === **false**) returnValue.processData = processData;
    if (contentType === **false**) returnValue.contentType = contentType;
}
```

And call them up in this way

```
$.ajax(getAJAXcall(post_setting[0], post_setting[1], formData, function(result) 
  { ...my callback functions... }
```

Also i try to change the post_setting = new Array(false,false); to true, true but the result was the same

Comment: `var formData = new FormData(form[0]);`

Comment: what should be form[0] and for what should it be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316120/jquery-formdata-doesnt-work

Comment: i dont wont to use the form datas, i want to create a new data-variable and put the wanted informations by hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the [right method call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) for this, so presumably there's something else wrong.

<del>Could `FormData` be overwritten by some other library (perhaps a polyfill), that knows nothing of `.append()`? Check the console of your browser for `FormData` and see, if you can spot anything fishy there.</del>

You use the result in a jQuery AJAX call, true? Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390646/113195) applies to you. In a nutshell, add

```
processData: false,
```

to your AJAX parameters.

Comment: i try it but the result was the same, i add some more infos in the main question

Comment: maybe the ajax-call function has  a error, if i code it by hand "processData:false," it will work fine!

Comment: the function has a important error - so i've update the question, by using processData: false; all will work fine :-)